# How to make modal tabs required? Also how to handle seperated forms with a single submit button? Laravel

Tags: html, laravel, validation, modal-dialog

I am working on a modal that adds the product. The modal has seperated tabs which is needed to add details. The question is that how can I handle validation.

Each tab has own form and submit button is the same. Also the "required" rule is not working. Any help please ?

Edit: Html code added. Don't read description after here. Because text is mostly code so I need to add more description. Also is there a way to handle this issue.

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="product_add_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="tab_modal">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header p-b-15">

          <h4 class="modal-title">Product Setup</h4>
          <ul class="card-actions icons right-top">

            <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-dismiss="modal" class="text-white" aria-label="Close">
              <i class="zmdi zmdi-close"></i>
            </a>

          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body p-0">
          <div class="tabpanel">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs p-0">
              <li class="active" role="presentation"><a href="#product_add_general" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true">General Info</a></li>
              <li role="presentation"><a href="#product_add_images" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true">Product Images</a></li>
              <li role="presentation"><a href="#product_add_price" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true">Price</a></li>
              <li role="presentation"><a href="#product_add_inventory" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true">Inventory</a></li>
              <li role="presentation"><a href="#product_add_shipping" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true">Shipping</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane fadeIn active" id="product_add_general">
              <div class="card card p-20 p-t-10 m-b-0">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <form class="form-horizontal" action="/somewhere" method="POST">
                      @csrf
                    <div class="form-group label-floating is-empty">
                      <label class="control-label">Title</label>
                      <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <textarea id="add_product_desc" required></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="chips chips-placeholder"></div>
                  </form>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fadeIn" id="product_add_images">
              <div class="card card p-20 p-t-10 m-b-0">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <form action="#" class="dropzone" id="product_add_images_form" enctype="multipart/form-data"></form>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fadeIn" id="product_add_price">
              <div class="card card p-20 p-t-10 m-b-0">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <form>
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group label-floating is-empty">
                          <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                            <label class="control-label">Price</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control">
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group label-floating is-empty">
                          <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                            <label class="control-label">Compare at price</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control">
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <div class="togglebutton m-b-15 ">
                            <label>
                              <input type="checkbox" class="toggle-info" checked>   Charge taxes on this product
                            </label>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </form>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fadeIn" id="product_add_inventory">
              <div class="card card p-20 p-t-10 m-b-0">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <form>
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group label-floating is-empty">
                          <label class="control-label">SKU (Stock Keeping Unit)</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group label-floating is-empty">
                          <label class="control-label">Barcode (ISBN, UPC, GTIN, etc.)</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label for="" class="control-label">Inventory policy</label>
                          <select class="select form-control">
                            <option selected>Don't track inventory</option>
                            <option>Track this product's inventory</option>
                          </select>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </form>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fadeIn" id="product_add_shipping">
              <div class="card card p-20 p-t-10 m-b-0">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <form>
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group label-floating is-empty">
                          <label class="control-label">Width</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group label-floating is-empty">
                          <label class="control-label">Height</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group label-floating is-empty">
                          <label class="control-label">Depth</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group label-floating is-empty">
                          <div class="input-group">
                            <label class="control-label">Weight</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="...">
                            <div class="input-group-btn suffix-select">
                              <select class="select form-control">
                                <option>lb</option>
                                <option>kg</option>
                              </select>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group label-floating is-empty">
                          <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                            <label class="control-label">Extra Shipping Fee</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control">
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </form>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-flat" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add Product</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- modal-content -->
      </div>
      <!-- modal-dialog -->
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: could you provide some of your code ? aksi halde hunharca eksi atacaklar hacı

Comment: Sure. Bi dakika atıyorum. :)

Comment: You cannot have multiple forms with a single submit button. You should probably group the forms under one `<form>` tag.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I added the html template. You may want to look at it.

Comment: are you using the same controller/method for saving these products ?

Comment: Yes.I am using store method on the ProductsController.

Comment: it seems there are many froms for products. So you can store each product on different method with different rules ?

Comment: What you mean by that? Isn't it too long way ? Let me ask that, Can I make a single form and remove all other, is it work? what do you think?

Comment: Bu satın alınmış templete. çok düzgün bişeye benzemiyor. Ben bunun tek form olmasını istiyorum ama yapıyı bozar mı emin değilim. yeniyim biraz.

Comment: Yapmaya çalıştığın şeyi tam olarak bilmeden html konusunda bir şey diyemem. Ama ortak alanlar varsa, sadece üründen ürüne bir kaç kısım değişiyorsa bir tane form oluşturup değişen kısımları javascript ile oluşturabilirsin. Soruna gelirsek eğer tek bir method içinde ürünleri kontrol edip depolamak istiyorsan aşağıda bir cevap yazıcam o yöntemi kullanabilirsin.

Comment: Şöyle düşün. Ürünleri bir sayfada gösteriyorum ve yanında bir + butonu var. Bu artı butonuna tıklayınca yeni ürün ekle sekmesi geliyor. burdaki her form olarak gösterilen yer aslında tek form olması lazım. çünkü ürün göstelilecek ürünün özelliklerini dolduruyorum.

Comment: ow anladım, o zaman her bir ürün için ayrı ayrı form oluşturucan ki bu da hunharca bir html demek. en iyisi javascript ile ürün türüne göre doldur modalın içini hocam :/ foreache sokacaksın o formları çok büyük bir html olacak ki seo açısından hiç iyi değil

Comment: Damn! Bakalım başka bir yol bulabilecek miyim. Sağolasın hocam.